# Foreign key constraint incorrectly formed but for the same type (Varchar(64))

Tags: sql, mariadb, foreign-keys

I've created 2 tables for my mariadb (*item_general_info and recieving_item*) with the 2nd table has a foreign key constraint, but the foreign key contraint cause an error (**errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrecly formed"**)

here's the query for the item_general_info:

```
CREATE TABLE Item_General_Info (UID VARCHAR(6) PRIMARY KEY,
                                name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
                                Category VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
                                does_expire INT(1) NOT NULL) COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CI;
```

and here's the recieving_item:

```
CREATE TABLE recieving_item(NAME VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL REFERENCES item_general_info.name,
                            stock INT(11) NOT NULL,
                            supp_name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
                            recieving_data DATE NOT NULL,
                            reciever VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS,
                            state INT (1) NOT NULL)COLLATE = latin1_general_ci
```

they're both varchar(64) and even had the same collation and both are can't be null, but there's still an error, any reasons why?

make a successful foreign key constraint from the 2nd table

Comment: I _think_ Mariadb requires the fk to reference a key. (pk, unique etc.)

Comment: Try adding the fk as a separate table constraint, i.e. `foreign key (name) references Item_General_Info (name)`,

Comment: name must be Pimary key .. maybe you need `NAME VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL REFERENCES Item_General_Info(UID)` https://dbfiddle.uk/AFAGZCZB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your foreign key restriction is that you are attempting to use a certain column of the item_general_info table as a key even though it is not declared as such. A unique column or a primary key column of the parent table should be the target of the foreign key. Since the name column in item_general_info is not unique nor the table's primary key, you are attempting to refer to it in this instance.

In the item_general_info table, a new primary key column has to be defined in order to address issue. The table's PRIMARY KEY may be changed to a new column named id. Below is how you can modify the item_general_info table:

```
CREATE TABLE Item_General_Info (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    UID VARCHAR(6) UNIQUE,
    name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    Category VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    does_expire INT(1) NOT NULL
) COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CI;
```

**recieving_item** table:

```
CREATE TABLE recieving_item(
    item_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    stock INT(11) NOT NULL,
    supp_name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    recieving_data DATE NOT NULL,
    reciever VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS,
    state INT (1) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES item_general_info(id)
) COLLATE = latin1_general_ci;
```

The foreign key for the receiving_item table is the new id column of the item_general_info table. The foreign key constraint problem should be resolved as a result.